# Error updating spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have this code on an Activity, I go back and again to this activity and update ArrayList datos.

```
{ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador =       
   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, datos);

spinnerD = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerD.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

when I try to open the spinner after "reopening" the activity I get the following Error:

```
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:376)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:329)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:325)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at com.android.internal.widget.WeightedLinearLayout.onMeasure(WeightedLinearLayout.java:60)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-08 04:13:14.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 04:13:16.052: ERROR/MetadataRetrieverClient(33): failed to extract an album art
```

Comment: have you used spinnerD.setAdapter(adaptador); ? Also, what line of code is 355?

Comment: That error isn't even an error, just a reference to a line of code. What is the full error text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spinnerD.setAdapter(adaptador1);
```

what is adaptador1, you are creating 'adaptador' and then you are setting adaptador1 to your `spinnerD.setAdapter(adaptador1)`. is this correct ? 'adaptador1' might be null/empty..

Comment: You mean that it should be empty or that is empty and that's why i have the error? adaptador is not empty before I do spinnerD.setAdapter(adaptador)